# Sorting two histograms in the same plot with ggplot

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I have a problem that I have not been able to find a solution for. I have a data frame with different adjectives and participles that are found in two different patterns.

```
head(THAT_EXT_COMBINED)
          ID  PATTERN         NODE
1  HRE_721_03 THAT_EXT     accepted
2 G08_1321_01 THAT_EXT acknowledged
3   AAW_47_03 THAT_EXT acknowledged
4 G20_1490_01 THAT_EXT     alarming
5  FY8_732_02 THAT_EXT      amazing
6  HEM_128_03 THAT_EXT      amazing

str(THAT_EXT_COMBINED)
'data.frame':   1450 obs. of  3 variables:
$ ID     : Factor w/ 1450 levels "A05_253_01","A05_277_07",..: 1109 827 265 853 812 1046 369 810 214 41 ...
$ PATTERN: Factor w/ 2 levels "THAT_EXT","THAT_POST": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ NODE   : Factor w/ 201 levels "accepted","acknowledged",..: 1 2 2 6 8 8 8 10 12 15 ...
```

I want to plot the adjectives of these two patterns in decreasing frequency using two histograms in the same plot. The problem is that there is some overlap between the two (i.e. some adjectives are found in both patterns) but I just want each histogram to start with the most frequent adjective.

Here is the code that I have been using for the sorting when producing individual histograms:

```
THAT_EXT_COMBINED <- within(THAT_EXT_COMBINED,
                            NODE <- factor(NODE,
                                           levels=names(sort(table(NODE),
                                                             decreasing=TRUE))))
```

I understand why this doesn't work since it combines the frequency of the two patterns but I still don't know how to solve it. I've been trying reorder() without any luck. Any ideas?

Here is the code I'm using for the plot:

```
graph<-ggplot(THAT_EXT_COMBINED, aes(x=NODE, fill=PATTERN)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth=.5,  position="dodge")
graph + opts(axis.text.x = theme_blank()) + #removes text labels on x-axis
scale_y_continuous("Frequency") + 
scale_x_discrete("Adjectives",breaks=NULL)+ 
opts(title = expression("Distribution of Adjectives"))
```

The problem with the resulting plot is that the adjectives are not strictly ordered by their respective frequency in the two patterns. Can anyone help with this?

---

So, here is the graph that I created with the code above. What I want instead is that the adjectives for each pattern are plotted in decreasing order, i.e. that both histograms are plotted in decreasing order by frequency. I guess this boils down to a sorting question, and I have tried to order the factors in different ways but I have not been able to do so first by PATTERN and within that by frequency of the NODE:

[image]

Comment: I think you may have to summarize your data before hand to be able to use reorder()

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape)
df <- cast(THAT_EXT_COMBINED, PATTERN ~.) 
colnames(df)[2] <- "Counts"

ggplot(df, aes(reorder(PATTERN, Counts), Counts, fill=PATTERN))
    + geom_bar(position="dodge") # + ...
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as I only get one bar for each pattern (even after correcting the typo in reorder() and changing to geom_histogram()). I have edited the post to show which type of plot I want to create.

Comment: Added position="dodge". Although, it's not really clear what your data "looks like". Maybe something like `head(THAT_EXT_COMBINED)` would be helpful.

Comment: I have edited the post to include information on the structure of the data. As I see it, it is a question of how to order the factors first by PATTERN and then by frequency of the NODE within the two PATTERNs.

Comment: Which PATTERN takes priority? (One is always going to be in front of the other if you use position="dodge")

Comment: That doesn't really matter to me although I prefer the order I have now with THAT_EXT first. What is crucial is that the NODES of each pattern are plotted in a strictly decreasing order (in terms of frequency), which is not case right now as you can see from the graph.